# How can one synchronize nested ajax calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have

```
function SomeFunc() {
  $.when($.ajax()).then(FunctionWhichDoesMoreAjax());
}
```

Now I need to wrap another call around this one.

`$.when(SomeFunc()).then(FunctionWhichDoesMoreAjax2());`

I tried modifying `SomeFunc()`

```
function SomeFunc() {
  return $.when($.ajax()).then(return FunctionWhichDoesMoreAjax());
}
```

But, this broke the functionality entirely.  The IDE reports error

> Expected Expression

at **return** `FunctionWhichDoesMoreAjax());`

How am I supposed to sync these up?

Comment: See Dmitry's answer; I assumed because of the `return` before `FunctionWhichDoesMoreAjax()` that you were ultimately trying to return a value from its success callback. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
function SomeFunc() {
  return $.when($.ajax()).then(FunctionWhichDoesMoreAjax);
}
```

Comment: I read the question as being able to chain two ajax calls.  The OP didn't say he wanted a return value from the second function.  If that's the case, then I agree with your answer that this can't be done  with asynchronous calls.

Comment: Deleted my original comment; that might work if `FunctionWhichDoesMoreAjax` is also a `$.when(...).then(function () {...})`; I'm not sure what the return value would be.

Comment: @Dmitry Beransky - The return values are not passed from function to function.  Only the calls need to happen in the proper order.  I think something similar to what you posted will work.  I have successfully used when to chain two calls, just never done it with three.  Toying with it now.

Comment: then(...) takes a callback (a function object), so you can chain calls ad infinitum:  function SomeFunc() {
  $.when($.ajax()).then(function() {
  $.when($.ajax()).then(function() {...});
}});
}

Comment: Thanks man, that last comment solved it.  I needed one more $.when and we are good to go.  The code is not pretty, but it fits the requirement!

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to send an id to the server side controller that handles the Ajax request.
A good way for usability, have in your mind that you can use a two position array in all cases.
First position will have the id of the request and the second the data for example json data or anything else.
When the server side finishes its job, it sends the response back to the page with in an array also the same pattern, id, data and your done. You can send async in your page without worrying to mix up the requests.

```
function request1(){
    data=getdata;
    arrData={1,data};
    ajaxsent(controler,data,onresponse1);

}

function request2(){
    data=getdata
    arrData={2,data};
    ajaxsent(controler,data,onresponse2);
}

function request3(){
    data=getdata;
    arrData={3,data};

    ajaxsent(controler,data,onresponse3);
}

function request4(){
    data=getdata;
    arrData={4,data};
    ajaxsent(controler,data,onresponse4);
}

function onresponse1(xml){
    synchronizer(xml);
}

function onresponse2(xml){
    synchronizer(xml);
}

function onresponse3(xml){
    synchronizer(xml);
}

function onresponse4(xml){
    synchronizer(xml);
}

function synchronizer(xml){
    switch(xml.id)
    case 1: dostuff;
    case 2: dostuff;
    case 3: dostuff;
    case 4: dostuff;

}
```